# Android Studio: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'

Tags: android, android-studio

First of all, I've read all other solution posts and the official documentation on migrating to 1.0. So far, none has worked.

Error:

```
Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'SparkDatabase' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

Apply Gradle plugin

Currently, this is my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ca.industrycorp.sparkdatabase"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:1.3.1'
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
}
```

My other gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Alternatively: How do I make a fresh installation of Android Studio 1.0 that would simply work out of the box, without having to relate to the 0.9 that I had before?

Comment: I had no luck upgrading from a version that was < 1.0.  I downloaded the app and installed a fresh copy.

Comment: My top-level gradle file looks like yours except the repository is mavenCentral rather than jcenter.  I don't know anything about it, but could there be a different syntax or keyword when using jcenter?  Also your question text doesn't match the error message.

Comment: Did you fix it by switching to mavenCentral, or something else?

Comment: @nasch I basically reinstalled it, but this time, after uninstallation, I went to Android and Android Studio folders and deleted all the trailing files that I could before installation. I tried reinstallation without doing that before, and the error persisted.

Answer (score 3):

By putting classpath in top level build.gradle , it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 build.gradle files. I found this error when I was adding classpath in the first one(The file that had all complied dependencies). The other one already had some classpath lines(or whatever you call them).