# Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavencentral()'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use facebook SDK in my android apps, and I am starting to add maven central repository to my `build.gardle`. Although, I've found 2 `build.gardle` which belong to project and app. Here they are;

- Android Studio: **1.5.1**
- Gradle Version: **2.8**
- Android Plugin Version: **1.5.0**

**Build.gardle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavencentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavencentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gardle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Yet I get this following error during build;

> Gradle DSL method not found: mavencentral()

I have tried;

- [Checking both gardle files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614898/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-classpath)
- [Removing android compile dependencies that's actually should be there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851230/android-gradle-build-error9-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile)
- [Checking android `packagingOptions.exclude`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881092/build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-android)
- [Checking if there's android method in the gardle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409384/android-studio-build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-andro)

And, I haven't tried to [update my gardle or android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0), but I am just wondering whether it's really needed or I am doing something wrong with my `build.gardle`.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Facebook SDK page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) is clear. Add into your project/build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() //note the uppercase C
}
```

and into your project/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

Comment: Shit.. How can I miss that capital `C`.. But now I have another same issue which saying `Gradle DSL method not found: compile()`. Thanks btw..

Comment: because your compile the facebook sdk into the wrong gradle file ;)